# STL File from multiple layered surface areas

Tags: python, image, image-processing, 3d, stl-format

I have a series of images of a structure with different z values (each photo is taken 5µm higher than the last one).

I wrote a programm that calculates the area of the structure for each photo. I also have a list that stores this area for each photo as a binary image (background = black, area = white).

Since I basically have all 3 coordinates for my structure I think it should be possible to create a STL file to plot this structre in 3D space.

Since I never did anything in terms of 3D programming I don't really know how to do this.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Is there no software that does this? I’ve seen people print from CT and MRI scans, without any coding, so this functionality must exist.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but there's a lot of useful comments on here: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/715/point-cloud-to-stl-file